# Self Contained KMZ with Photos

Tags: kml, arcgis, esri, kmz, self-contained

Originally I created my KMZ file in ArcGIS 10.1 which included a latitude/longitude for some potential reclamation sites. In the end I have a a KMZ file when each placemark is clicked it pops up a information box that has a site description and a photo. The photos are currently stored online, I would like to get this KMZ file to contain the photos to make it easier for my web map to get published which uses ESRI's Javascript API to access the KMZ file. I have unzipped the KMZ file and attempted to change the absolute URL of the image to just the file name since all of the files are stored in the same directory. I then selected the KML file, the photo I tested this on, and my icon and zipped them, changed the file type from ZIP to KMZ and it does not work.

Comment: Local images on the placemark(information bubble) will not work on KMZ and kml in latest GE versions. If you would like to place image on placemark in kml of GE then add src="file:///&local url"

Comment: Thanks for your help! That is quite the bummer that you can not use local images.

Answer (score 0):

In the last step, try leaving them unzipped so the KML can access the image urls directly. The website accesses the KML and the KML points to the photo urls.